# "connect to hidden wireless Network" needs always admin authorization

Tags: wireless, menu, authentication

When I select "connect to the hidden wireless Network" from the gnome wireless Menu and select the preconfigured template, I get always an authorization box when logged in as normal user.

How can I make that normal users don't have to authenticate for connecting to a hidden wireless?

Answer (score 0):

Edit/or create the Policy Kit definition file that (may or may not be included with your installation

```
sudo nano /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

Insert or Find the following chunk

```
[Adding or changing system-wide NetworkManager connections]
Identity=unix-group:admin
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system
ResultActive=yes
```

Change

```
Identity=unix-group:admin
```

To read

```
Identity=unix-group:network-users
```

Create the group network-users

```
sudo addgroup network-users
```

Add yourself (repeat for other users, replacing $USER with their username)

```
sudo adduser $USER network-users
```

You may not have to restart for this to take effect.